# Diazepam with Aluminum Hydroxide

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, pharmacology, medicine, benzodiazepine

Some common medicinal preparations contain diazepam with aluminium Hydroxide, there may be other compounds [e.g. magnesium trisilicate and polydimethylsiloxane with Aluminum Hydroxide and Diazepam as ingredients of Tablet Peptica ( Geno pharmaceuticals)]. These drugs are commonly used as antacids. We can see in the drug Peptica that Aluminum Hydroxide and Magnesium Trisilicate were included for neutralizing the acidity (HCl) of stomach.....thus serving their purpose as antacids. Polydimethylsiloxane is a carminative preparation ('Carminative' means preparations that expulse gas from the gastrointestinal tract or prevent its formation). But what is the need for adding Diazepam here?

Comment: Diazepam is a very-much restricted medicine. It is sedative-tranquilizer (sleeping pill) also used in severe anxiety.  I've never seen any antacid-preparation containing diazepam. Maybe a sedative-tranquilizer preparation (maybe in mouth-dissolvable form) using some amount of antacid in it. or maybe in that tranquilizing preparation those antacid-materials just being used as a tablet base, with no functional role.

Comment: I'm not a doctor or medical professional however web search tells this particular brand is used to treat peptic ulcer. Maybe they're using it to calm-down the nervous-system of patient suffering from ulcer-pain. This question is more appropriate for a medicine or health community, than a biology community. Take professional Doctor's advice (not any web advice) for medicine use, and especially when it contains a restricted chemical.